# How to amend or change the size of a PopoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I have used a popoverPresentationController on iOS Swift and i have put both an image and text in the popover?

The issue i am having is that the content is too big for the popover? is it possible to set the dimensions?

Pictures are below of both the issue i am having and the trial code and error message?

```
  let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: "Correct answer selected, move on to next level", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
    {
        //  action in self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goSegue1", sender: self)

        self.musicEffect.stop()
    }
    // put image into action sheet
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: -30, width: 140, height: 140))
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "wellDone2.png")

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    myAlert.view.addSubview(imageView)

    // display the alert messgae

    myAlert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    myAlert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).frame
    myAlert.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 800)
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZTgC.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy and paste your actual code into the question. Do not post images of code.

Answer (score 5):

The size of the popover is not controlled by the `PopoverPresentationController`. The `PopoverPresentationController` only specifies how to present content, but the content itself, including size, is set by the view from which you have obtained the controller, in your case `myAlert`.

You have the right idea trying to set `preferredContentSize`, but you're setting it on the wrong view. You should change the line

```
popoverPresentationController?.preferredContentSize = /* ... */
```

to:

```
myAlert.preferredContentSize = /* ... */
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I have tried your suggestion but it is still not changing the overall dimensions of the alert?